# Formatting of Complex number in Sympy expression

Tags: python, math, sympy

I am trying to solve expression in SymPy.

```
x,c,m=symbols('x,c,m')
y = x**4 + sym.Rational(11/4)*(c/m)*(x**2)+(sym.Rational(3/2)*(c/m)**2)
solve(y,x)
```

Is there a way in Sympy where sqrt(-1) will automatically get formatted as ***i*** in the output expression instead of containing as -1 in the square root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation results in `[-sqrt(2)*sqrt(-c/m), sqrt(2)*sqrt(-c/m), -sqrt(3)*sqrt(-c/m)/2, sqrt(3)*sqrt(-c/m)/2]`. Without any hints, all variable can be complex, and `c/m` could be a positive real. There isn't a reason to bring `I` out of the square root. (Note that sympy [represents `I` with a capital](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#imaginaryunit).)

If, however, `c` and `m` are declared as real and positive, the output changes:

```py
import sympy as sym

c, m = sym.symbols('c,m', real=True, positive=True)
x = sym.symbols('x')
y = x ** 4 + sym.Rational(11 / 4) * (c / m) * (x ** 2) + (sym.Rational(3 / 2) * (c / m) ** 2)
sym.solve(y, x)
```

Result:

```
[-sqrt(2)*I*sqrt(c)/sqrt(m),
 sqrt(2)*I*sqrt(c)/sqrt(m),
 -sqrt(3)*I*sqrt(c)/(2*sqrt(m)),
 sqrt(3)*I*sqrt(c)/(2*sqrt(m))]
```